# how to check multiple edittext or textview empty or null?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a activity is contains 40 or 50 `EditText` ....(example like a ragistration form)

when I click submit button I have to maintain all `EditText` is null or empty (validation)

if I check one by one edittext

```
    if(ed_text.isEmpty() || ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || 
     ed_text == null)
     {
      //EditText is empty
     }
     else
     {
     //EditText is not empty
     }
```

My activity like all field with just only with its condition and its hard to maintain all `EditText` name check and put that Condition.

How can I manage in simple way without declare if conditions ....is there any solution for this problem as this is time consuming and also hard to  maintain data...or is there any library for to check this condition ?

and how to maintain its `Toast` like

```
      if firstname is empty : please enter firstname 
      if lastname is empty : please enter lastname
```

Answer (score 4):

Create Common function  `hasText` with error message and without error message

Common Message

```
 public static boolean hasText(EditText editText) {

            return hasText(editText,"Required")
        }
```

Custome Message

```
public static boolean hasText(EditText editText,String error_message) {

            String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            editText.setError(null);

            // length 0 means there is no text
            if (text.length() == 0) {
                editText.setError(error_message);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Validate the data

**Validate all at time**

```
private boolean Validate() {
            boolean check = true;
            if (!hasText(editFirstName)) check = false;
            if (!hasText(editLastName)) check = false;
            if (!hasText(editExtra,"Message temp")) check = false;

            return check;
        }
```

OR

**Validate one by one**

```
private boolean Validate() {

                if (!hasText(editFirstName)) return false;
                if (!hasText(editLastName)) return false;
                if (!hasText(editExtra)) return false;

                return true;
            }
```

How to Use

```
if(Validate())
{
//do your work
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, just pass error message parameter in **hasText** method for different message for different EditText

Comment: @Birju Bhatt  You can pass Error message in hasText(EditText editText,String errormsg)

Comment: it isn't saving much time. You still are forced to scroll line of 50 if statements.

Comment: Updated the answer for custom and default message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766882/edittext-multiple-edit-fill-check 

can You help me out with my problem ??

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to create an arrayList of EditTexts that require validation:

```
List<EditText> validationList = new ArrayList();

void init() {
    et = (...)
    validationList.add(et);
}

boolean validate() {
    for(EditText e : validationList) {
       if(!isValid(et))
          //display your message here
          return false;
    }
    return true;
    //Of course if you want to display message for all EditTexts validation faults just wait with returning "false". 
}

void boolean isValid(EditText et) {
    return et.isEmpty() || et.length() == 0 || et.equals("");
}
```

In such way it's easier to maintain different validations (is not empty, is string longer than etc.) - you just create different list.

**Think about using Kotlin**

This task would be much easer using Kotlin. You can create extension method for EditText to validate it. You can also create your custom EditTexts with delegate "getters" and "setters" for text property (eg Vetoable delegate).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766882/edittext-multiple-edit-fill-check 

can You help me out with my problem ??

Answer (score 1):

This extension helps to validate whether the EditText's value has a valid email, minimum and maximum length, etc. Find more details [EditText Extensions](https://cdan.me/android/kotlin-extensions/edittext/)

```
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText


/**
 * Created by Chathura Wijesinghe on 2019-06-12.
 * cdanasiri@gmail.com
 */

/**
 * This extension supports EditText validation such as emails, maximum and minimum length
 * */
fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(s.toString().trim())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
}

/**
 * You can validate the EditText like
 *
 * et_email.validate("Valid email address required"){ s -> s.isValidEmail() }
 *
 * et_email.validate("Minimum length is 6"){ s-> s.length>=6 }
 *
 * */
fun EditText.validate(message: String, validator: (String) -> Boolean) : Boolean{
    this.afterTextChanged {
        this.error = if (validator(it)) null else message
    }
    this.error = if (validator(this.getString())) null else message

    return validator(this.getString())
}

/**
 * @return String value of the EditTextView
 * */
fun EditText.getString(): String{
    return this.text.toString()
}

/**
 * @return Trimmed String value of the EditTextView
 * */
fun EditText.getStringTrim(): String{
    return this.getString().trim()
}
```

you can validate any condition like this

```
var isValid = et_email.validate("Minimum length is 4 "){ s-> s.length>=4 && s.length<=10 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do about it. Either you need to create a function to validate all the EditText and then call this function right before submitting data.

Another option is to use a validator library like this one [here](https://github.com/vekexasia/android-edittext-validator) or [here](https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation)