# EditText Multiple Edit Fill check

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

i am creating a project in which i have 3 Edit text filled i want to check if from 3 edit text any one should be filled any one from either 3 edit text i know how to check if all there is data in all edittext values

```
    private boolean validate_edit1() {
        string1= edit1.getText().toString().trim();
        if (string1.isEmpty()) {
            edit1.requestFocusFromTouch();
            edit1.setAnimation(shakeError());
            edit1.setError("");
            return false;
        } else {
            edit1.setFocusable(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validate_edit2() {
        string2= edit2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (string2.isEmpty()) {
            edit2.requestFocusFromTouch();
            edit2.setAnimation(shakeError());
            edit2.setError("");
            return false;
        } else {
            edit1.setFocusable(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validate_edit3() {
        string3= edit3.getText().toString().trim();
        if (string3.isEmpty()) {
            edit3.requestFocusFromTouch();
            edit3.setAnimation(shakeError());
            edit3.setError("");
            return false;
        } else {
            edit3.setFocusable(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void checking_all_data() {
        if (!validate_edit1()) {
            return;
        }
if (!validate_edit2()) {
            return;
        }
if (!validate_edit3()) {
            return;
        }
```

I want that from if any 3 edit text if one edittext have some data then it moves to next activity but this method is check if all the 3 edit text are empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. Check if at least 1 is filled out

```
private void checking_all_data() {
        if (validate_edit1() || validate_edit2() || validate_edit3()) {
            //success
        }
        else{
            //error
        }
    }
```

Comment: it worked for me but what if i have to send the value enter as it is and other values as null ?? can uh help me out with this too..??

Comment: You can send an array of String and manage nulls in the next activity

Comment: thnku for your guidance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790242/selected-item-id-in-spinner can uh help me outh from here also??

Comment: sir can uh please help me out ??